# Invalid diagnostics signature

Tags: swift

When I build my project and I don't know how, I got this type of warning:

```
Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Invalid File: Invalid diagnostics signature
```

It is just shows the name of class but did not mentioned any location.

Any advise?

Comment: No, I am not using SwiftLint. this is the first time I saw such type to warning

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is new as of Xcode 11.5, as far as I can tell, and it happens when you interrupt a running build. The warnings disappear when you let a new build run to completion.